# HTTP redirect not working in Windows Phone 8

Tags: php, windows-phone-8, http-redirect

I'm creating a website which redirects the user to a special mobile site if they are using a mobile device. Using an if statement in PHP, I first determine if the user is on a mobile device, and run this code if they are:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/mobile');
```

It works fine on my father's HTC Wildfire running the "browser" application, but on my mom's Nokia Lumia 521 running Internet Explorer on Windows Phone 8 gives an error page which says:
"We're having a problem displaying this website", and the redirect doesn't work. Any clues?
Code

```
<?php
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v   )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-  mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-   3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g     |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4))) {
header("Location: ../m/"); //redirect to mobile site
};
?>
```

Comment: Is it possible that the Windows phone is having some sort of network issue? Can it view other pages on the site? Does it still give you the error if you remove all `if` statements in the code and just serve up the redirect? Since this is working on another device I would lean toward it being an issue with the device.

Comment: After removing the 'if' statement, the redirect functions properly. But, I need the 'if' statement, or desktop users will go to the mobile site. How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that the Windows phone fails on but the others work with?

Answer (score -1):

try with status code

```
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
Header( "Location: http://www.new-url.com");
```

Comment: I will try this, but I can't see how this will help... any insight? Thanks for the answers, by the way.

Comment: you want detect mobile device and redirect to mobile website right ?

Comment: Yes... I added the line "header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently')"

Comment: here Joomla 3.x browser class https://github.com/ElectricEasel/angelbm/blob/master/libraries/joomla/environment/browser.php